# Short story where the rich live in towers and the poor live on the ground in the gloom

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The plot:

Cities have grown very tall and the rich live in the sky in the towers and the poor live on the ground where there is no sun. The families that have the skill and nerve to walk outside at great heights are the only ones who can do any repairs.

They have to go outside and repair something and there is a risk of either freezing or running out of oxygen. The main character is female and her father is also a character.

I read this in the mid to late 90’s so it is not new publication.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Jenerosity! These aren't a ton of details; if you want to improve this question, see [this great guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some tips.

Comment: So is the story about someone going outside to repair something?

Comment: Is this the story where people actually live in shelters roped to the side of a tower?

Comment: This is a very common trope in SF. Unless you can come up with more specific details it's going to be hard to answer as so many books fit the description.

Comment: Yes, they have to go outside and repair something and there is a risk of either freezing or running out of oxygen. The main character is female and her father is also a character.

Comment: The part about cities sort of reminds me of Terminal World by Alistair Reynolds, but the rest of it (female protagonist having to do repairs) sounds totally different.